# React Native - How to create the iPhone BedTime dial ?

Tags: react-native, css-animations

Can you please guide me into how I can implement the bedtime dial in react-native ?   I would like to implement the animation as well.

Please see the attached screenshot for reference.

Thanks and Kind Regards,
Avinash[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-native-circular-slider](https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-slider).

```
<CircularSlider
  startAngle={startAngle}
  angleLength={angleLength}
  onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
  segments={5}
  strokeWidth={40}
  radius={145}
  gradientColorFrom="#ff9800"
  gradientColorTo="#ffcf00"
  showClockFace
  clockFaceColor="#9d9d9d"
  bgCircleColor="#171717"
  stopIcon={<StopIcon/>}
  startIcon={<StartIcon/>}
/>
```

The complete example is mentioned [here](https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-slider/tree/master/example-exponent/Bedtime)